# How to change the return of a function to int?

Tags: reactjs

Just want to do a component for change the pages and return the value of the page, for an API. The first component is the class for change the page and the rest is where is returned the value on the onClick function of MovePage

```
export class MovePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.decrementPage = this.decrementPage.bind(this)
        this.incrementPage = this.incrementPage.bind(this)
    }

    render () {
        const incrementedPage = this.incrementPage
        return (
            <div className='changePage'>
                <button className='SelectionOff' id='decrement' onClick={()=>this.props.updatePage(this.decrementPage)}>Previous</button>
                <h1 className='changePageNumber'>{this.props.value}</h1>
                <button className='SelectionOff' id='increment' onClick={()=>this.props.updatePage(incrementedPage)}>Next</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
    decrementPage () {
        const newPage = this.props.value - 1
        return(newPage < 1 ? 1 : newPage )
      }
    incrementPage () {
        const newPage = this.props.value + 1
        return(typeof(newPage <= this.props.max ? newPage : this.props.value))
      }
}
```

and where is returned the argument

```
<MovePage value={this.state.page} max={this.state.max_pages} updatePage={this.updatePage}/>

 updatePage = (value) => {
    this.setState({page:value})
  }
```

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if
>   you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe
>   you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Next/Previous button. You pass a function `this.decrementPage` or `this. incrementPage` to `updatePage` function.

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.updatePage(this.decrementPage)}>Previous</button>
```

So the `value` in `updatePage` function is a function. After that, you set the `value` to `state` and display that value in `MovePage`

```
<h1 className='changePageNumber'>{this.props.value}</h1>
```

`this.props.value` is a function. That's why you get the warning. If you need to get value of `this.decrementPage` function. You need to call it `this.decrementPage()`.

Comment: Change your `onClick` function in button to something like `onClick={()=>this.props.updatePage(this.decrementPage())}`

Comment: instead of a number (1, 2, 3, ...) prints number

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: XD, nothing it was my testing of before, I was using typeof, sorry, and thanks for the information